# Error importing data using requests - python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access data from this webpage: https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/# using the "Ship Movements" tab.
I've attempted to use the url service request but keep getting errors.

Currently, I've tried:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

url = 'https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/services/wxdata.svc/GetDataX'

payload = {
"token": None,
"reportCode": "MSQ-WEB-0001",
"dataSource": None,
"filterName": "Last 7 days",
"parameters": [{
        "__type": "ParameterValueDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO",
        "sName": "DOMAIN_ID",
        "iValueType": 0,
        "aoValues": [{"Value": -1}],
              }],
"metaVersion": 0,
}

jsonData = requests.post(url, data = payload).json()
```

Which returns the following error:

```
{'ExceptionDetail': {'HelpLink': None, 'InnerException': None, 'Message': "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.", 'StackTrace': '   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)', 'Type': 'System.InvalidOperationException'}, 'ExceptionType': 'System.InvalidOperationException', 'Message': "The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.", 'StackTrace': '   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DemultiplexingDispatchMessageFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.UriTemplateDispatchFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)'}
```

When I alter the json dict, I'm getting the following error:

```
jsonData = requests.post(url, json={'key':'value'}).json()

{'ExceptionDetail': None, 'ExceptionType': None, 'Message': 'WebX.Security.EAuthError: Request does not belong to an authenticated session.', 'StackTrace': None}
```

Can the data be accessed through a request or will I have to scrape it?

Comment: "*I think I need a more flexible parser*" Ok, so have you made an attempt at implementing "*a more flexible parser*" on your own before posting here in accordance with [ask]? Can you share that attempt here as a [mre]?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more nuanced. I don't know if it's the actual data structure that's causing the breakdown or the fact it's being constantly refreshed. I've tried multiple methods. Happy to list them all to show current working. Probably get downvoted because the question won't be clear.

Comment: You're still getting the data in a single page, but the page is updated using JavaScript, therefore the answer to this question is the same answer that's been given to 90% of bs4 questions on SO: there's JavaScript involved, you need to use an engine that parses and runs the JavaScript, try `selenium`. And on top of that: you could have a look at the actual code underneath the webpage - it's quite possible you can just make the web service requests that the JS makes yourself directly and skip scraping altogether.

Comment: Thanks. This was the advice I was after. I searched more questions that included 'updated' or 'refreshed' data but couldn't find anything. I feel like this question isn't appreciate that much so happy to delete or reconfigure so it provides some high-level info on where to get started.

Comment: That's absolutely not "the same error". That's a different error. One is saying your content type is incorrect (`data=` will send `application/octet-stream`, `json=` will send `application/json`, which is more correct here), the other is saying you're not authenticated.

Comment: Amended. I can't find anything on the latter. So the second amends the first error but I'm still unable to import data because I'm not authenticated?

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a header specifying the nature of your request? This is often the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the requests that the linked web UI makes, this script seems to be able to access *some* data.

The JSON payload for the data query is different from the original post, so something will probably need to be adapted there.

The kicker is, in any case, that you need to use a `requests.Session()`, and make a request to the web UI first to acquire a session cookie.

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests

get_session_url = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/"
get_data_url = "https://qships.tmr.qld.gov.au/webx/services/wxdata.svc/GetDataX"
get_data_query = {
    "token": None,
    "reportCode": "MSQ-WEB-0001",
    "dataSource": None,
    "filterName": "Next 7 days",
    "parameters": [
        {
            "__type": "ParameterValueDTO:#WebX.Core.DTO",
            "sName": "DOMAIN_ID",
            "iValueType": 0,
            "aoValues": [{"Value": -1}],
        }
    ],
    "metaVersion": 0,
}

sess = requests.session()

sess.get(get_session_url).raise_for_status()

json_data = sess.post(
    get_data_url,
    json=get_data_query,
).json()

pprint(json_data)
```

prints out (e.g.)

```
{'d': {'BuildVersion': '7.0.0.12590',
       'ReportCode': 'MSQ-WEB-0001',
       'Tables': [{'AsOfDate': '16:33 on Jan 17',
                   'BuildVersion': '7.0.0.12590',
                   'Data': [[132058,
                             334359,
                             'EXT',
                             'STOLT MOMIJI',
                             'TANKER',
                             121.52,
...
```

Comment: Thanks AKX. I'll tidy up the question

Comment: when you say _some_ data, do you mean it's not _all_ the data. Or has limited uses. I'm trying to `normalise` the data and return a pandas df so it replicates the tabular structure displayed on the webpage

Comment: I don't know if it's the correct data you need.

Comment: Good point. There tabular structure corresponding with `Data`